# highcharts with number_format

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

i'm working with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), and i'm having some problem with `number_format`.

formating the number `$variable = 1008000` :

`number_format($variable, 2,',','.')`

the result is: `1.008.000,00` (this is what i need)

but, highcharts transform  **`1.008.000,00`** to **`1.008`**

how can i deal with this problem?

Comment: What do you actually want to output to be?

Comment: well, output must be `1.008.000,00`

Comment: This will probably boil down to your use of a more international format.  It is seeing your periods as just that, periods.  So 1.008.000 isn't one million... it's one point zero zero eight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that in English the number should be 1,008,000.00
You could either change it in your number_format() call or try changing the decimal point value in Hightcharts (http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#lang)

Comment: let me know how can you differ the 1,008,000.00 this comma (,) and array separated coma (,) in array see this [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]

Comment: Hi , I'm very new to this and would like to know if we have language support for highcharts.It would be great if you could help me. Thanks :)

Comment: @ishhhh I'm not using Highcharts myself, but there's a part on `i18n` in the docs: http://docs.highcharts.com/#internationalization or more specifically the `lang` option in the API docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang

Comment: @uuisari Thanks 4 the reply. I think this will help me . :) .

Answer (score 0):

note one thing, we do not need to set the number format for high chart...
you can pass directly 1008000 it will be auto adjust with this value...
Check this...Good luck
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from lang parameters http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#lang.thousandsSep you can also use Highcharts.numberFormat() for labels / tooltip which can be used in formatter .

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.numberFormat()
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter